# Getting pushsharp unknown transport error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I am using pushsharp library on server side to generate push notification to android and iOS devices. Everything was working fine earlier and notifications were received. But suddenly I have started receiving following error:

> Unknown Transport Error    at
> PushSharp.Android.GcmPushChannel.processResponseError(GcmAsyncParameters
> asyncParam)    at
> PushSharp.Android.GcmPushChannel.responseCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Push notifications are not being received on mobile devices now.

Comment: There's a similar in [github](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/200) with this issue, kindly check the solution offered from the other developers.

Comment: @jess In github the link provided for solution is not working. I have already gone through that. Any other help would be highly appreciated.